# Will the same Wordpress logins work after a site migration?

Tags: login, migration

I am about to migrate my site to a new host, after the site and database is migrated over, will I be able to login to the back end with the same username & password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  User login data is stored in the DB which will not change in your example.